# Butterknife and fragments

Tags: android, butterknife

Im working with Butterknife and I have a problem, when I want to change a fragment for another, the app fails. This is my first fragment

```
@Bind(R.id.tilNombre) TextInputLayout tilNombres;
@Bind(R.id.tilApellido) TextInputLayout tilApellido;
@Bind(R.id.tilDocumento) TextInputLayout tilDocumento   ;
@Bind(R.id.btnContinuar) Button btnContinuar;
public RegistroFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registro, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    app();
}

void app(){
    tilNombres.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.nombres));
    tilApellido.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.apellidos));
    tilDocumento.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.licencia));

    events();
}

void events(){

    btnContinuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RegistroTwoFragment registroTwoFragment = new RegistroTwoFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenedorRegistro, registroTwoFragment).commit();
        }
    });
}
```

In that code I dont have any problem, the problem is in the next part

```
public class RegistroTwoFragment extends Fragment {

@Bind(R.id.tilCorreo) TextInputLayout tilCorreo;
@Bind(R.id.tilClave) TextInputLayout tilClave;
@Bind(R.id.btnRegistrar) TextInputLayout btnRegistrar;
@Bind(R.id.tviRetroceder) TextInputLayout tviRetroceder;

public RegistroTwoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registro_two, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    app();
}

void app(){
    tilCorreo.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.correo));
    tilClave.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.contrasena));

    events();
}

void events(){
    tviRetroceder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RegistroFragment registroFragment = new RegistroFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenedorRegistro, registroFragment).commit();
        }
    });
}
```

The logcat says: Unable to bind views for com.example.aato.ciudadano.fragments.RegistroTwoFragment; does anyone know the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1. Make sure that the `fragment_registro_two` layout actually contains the resource IDs used in your `@Bind(R.id.xyz)` statements.
2. Make sure that you are using the correct type for every variable bound to each resource. In your case, are you sure that `TextInputLayout` is actually the right type for all bound resources?